# Regex in notepad++ to search all emails to excluding one address

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I have a very large email headers export for a user at work, and need to find and mark specific lines within the document and I'm struggling. I've marked all of the from: specificuser@company.com, date and message id lines, but I'm struggling with finding a way to mark all of the to: anyuser@companies while excluding specificuser@company from being marked.

I only want to mark his outgoing not incoming.

Basically what I need to mark is all of the following:

```
From: specificuser@company.com
To: anyaddress@companies.com
Date: anydate
Message-ID: <anything@company.com>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @hwnd: I don't know, however nice mustache.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good one =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ accepts the lookahead syntax. A [lookahead assertion](http://regular-expressions.com/lookaround.html) `(?=...)` will check what happen on the right of the current regex engine position. But for your specific case, a negative lookahead `(?!...)` *(that ensure there is not someting)* is more appropriate:

Example: I assume that all elements of the headers are at the start of a line:

```
^From: (?!specificuser@company\.com$).+\r?\nTo: [^@]+@companies$
```

This will match the two first lines of each headers that are not send by `specificuser@company`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This got me close enough that I was able to do exactly what I needed. You're a life saver.